Jolt Spec transformation with nested Array structure
I have a json like
{
  "Product": [
    {
      "id": 123,
      "name": "foo",
      "ProductCharge": [
        {
          "productCode": "PIIB",
          "configLevel": "PROD",
          "feeRate": [
            {
              "rate": 123,
              "range": "123"
            },
            {
              "rate": 321,
              "range": "321"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

which I want transformed to this
{
  "Product" : [ {
    "id": 123,
      "name": "foo",
   // more fields
    "ProductCharge" : [ {
      "productCode" : "PIIB",
      "configLevel" : "PROD",
      "rate" : 123,
      "range" : "123"
    }, {
      "productCode" : "PIIB",
      "configLevel" : "PROD",
      "rate" : 321,
      "range" : "321"
    } ]
  } ]
}

I have this spec,
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Product": {
        "*": {
          // Preserve the id, name, and any other top-level fields
          "ProductCharge": {
            "*": {
              "feeRate": {
                "*": {
                  "@2": { "*": "Product[#6].ProductCharge.[&1].&" },
                  "*": "Product[#6].ProductCharge.[&1].&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "Product": {
        "*": {
          "ProductCharge": {
            "*": {
              "feeRate": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


My current spec is missing the "id" and "name" and the other fields under "Product". If I try to add this line to get the remaining fields under "Product", it distorts the whole structure
"*": "Product[#2].&"

Can someone point out how to get around this.
Edit:
Barbaros's your solution worked, but I realized when I have more than one ProductCharge like below
{
  "Product": [
    {
      "id": 123,
      "name": "foo",
      "ProductCharge": [
        {
          "aboveAmount": 0,
          "chargeType": "ABC",
          "chargeValueType": "PERCENT",
          "frequency": 1,
          "feeRate": [
            {
              "bandNumber": 1,
              "rate": 0.6
            },
            {
              "bandNumber": 2,
              "rate": 1.7
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "aboveAmount": 0,
          "chargeType": "DEF",
          "chargeValueType": "PERCENT",
          "frequency": 1,
          "feeRate": [
            {
              "bandNumber": 1,
              "rate": 0.75
            },
            {
              "bandNumber": 2,
              "rate": -0.55
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

rather than create it as 4 separate sections
{
  "Product" : [ {
    "id" : 123,
    "name" : "foo",
    "ProductCharge" : [ {
      "aboveAmount" : 0,
      "chargeType" : "ABC",
      "chargeValueType" : "PERCENT",
      "frequency" : 1,
      "bandNumber" : 1,
      "rate" : 0.6
    }, {
      "aboveAmount" : 0,
      "chargeType" : "ABC",
      "chargeValueType" : "PERCENT",
      "frequency" : 1,
      "bandNumber" : 2,
      "rate" : 1.7
    }, {
      "aboveAmount" : 0,
      "chargeType" : "DEF",
      "chargeValueType" : "PERCENT",
      "frequency" : 1,
      "bandNumber" : 1,
      "rate" : 0.75
    }, {
      "aboveAmount" : 0,
      "chargeType" : "DEF",
      "chargeValueType" : "PERCENT",
      "frequency" : 1,
      "bandNumber" : 2,
      "rate" : -0.55
    } ]
  } ]
}

it creates like this;
{
  "Product" : [ {
    "id" : 123,
    "name" : "foo",
    "ProductCharge" : [ {
      "aboveAmount" : [ 0, 0 ],
      "chargeType" : [ "ABC", "DEF" ],
      "chargeValueType" : [ "PERCENT", "PERCENT" ],
      "frequency" : [ 1, 1 ],
      "bandNumber" : [ 1, 1 ],
      "rate" : [ 0.6, 0.75 ]
    }, {
      "aboveAmount" : [ 0, 0 ],
      "chargeType" : [ "ABC", "DEF" ],
      "chargeValueType" : [ "PERCENT", "PERCENT" ],
      "frequency" : [ 1, 1 ],
      "bandNumber" : [ 2, 2 ],
      "rate" : [ 1.7, -0.55 ]
    } ]
  } ]
}


Welcome to SO Mahesh

You can handle the issue better by accumulating the inner stuff( those within the "feeRate" array ) in a new object, namely "Others" while using placeholder ampersand symbols for the keys such as "Product", "ProductCharge" and "feeRate" such that
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Product": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[&1].&",
          "ProductCharge": {
            "*": {
              "*": "&4[&3].&2[&1].Others.&",
              "feeRate": "&4[&3].&2[&1].&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Product": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[&1].&",
          "ProductCharge": {
            "*": {
              "feeRate": {
                "*": {
                  "@2,Others": { "*": "&7[&6].&5[&1].&" },
                  "*": "&6[&5].&4[&1].&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site Jolt Transform Demo Using v0.1.1 is :

Edit : You'll need to add one more partition for this new case and the expression &3_&1 will do the trick such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Product": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.&",
          "ProductCharge": {
            "0": { //in order to bring only once among duplicated values
              "*": "&4.&2.Others.&",
              "feeRate": {
                "*": {
                  "*": "&6.&4.&2.&3_&1.&"
                }
              }
            },
            "*": {
              "feeRate": {
                "*": {
                  "*": "&6.&4.&2.&3_&1.&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Product": {
        "*": "&1[0].&",
        "ProductCharge": {
          "feeRate": {
            "*": {
              "@": "&4[0].&3.[#2]",
              "@2,Others": { "*": "&5[0].&4.[#3].&" }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

This last spec will handle the previous case as well

Thank you Barbaros. This worked as expected, but when I plugged in an additional ProductCharge, it seems to be collapsing them into an array, rather separate object structure;

I added the updated section and marked it with Edit: . Let me know if that was done correct

Barbaros, I just noticed that I had overlooked the fact that the transformation is keeping the values in Others matching the first ProductCharge object. Even they need to change related to the ProductCharge. So the values for aboveAmount, chargeType etc. will also need to be changing. I tried mucking around with the way it is constructued, but did not have luck getting it right

not sure if you got a change to see my last comment. I spent some time trying to get the transformation to work for Others also being dynamic for each ProductCharge, but I did not succeed. When you get a few minutes, can you check pls @BarbarosÖzhan

follow up question posted here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932029/jolt-spec-transformation-with-nested-array-structure-follow-up
